# How to setup authentication when using a combination of Azure AD and a custom database to store user accounts?

Tags: user-management, membership-provider, identity-server

I am using SXC 9.0.2. I have an Azure AD and would like to let Azure AD accounts access both the Content Editor and the Commerce Business Tools. End-users will also need to sign-in - these users will reside in a custom database that I have control of.

**What is the best approach in terms of setting up authentication to cover all this?**

[This guide](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-management/en/configure-federated-authentication.html) explains how to set up authentication for Azure AD, but I guess it only covers the Content Editor part, as it doesn't involve Sitecore Identity Server.

[This guide](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/use-the-sitecore-identity-server-as-a-federation-gateway.html) explains how to set up Azure AD authentication via the Sitecore Identity Server but as I understand it, this only covers the Commerce Business Tools. Furthermore, this guide is only available for 9.1.

[This guide](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/authentication-and-authorization.html) indicates that I need to use an ASP.NET Membership Provider to have end-users in a separate database (section: "Other security providers")

Does that mean I need all three providers?

- ASP.NET Identity to sign in Azure AD users in the Content Editor
- Sitecore Identity Server to sign in Azure AD users in the Commerce Business Tools
- ASP.NET Membership Provider to sign in end-users from custom database

Best case for me would be to have a single authentication service provider to handle users in all three cases and use the domain (sitecore, extranet) to identify the external user store. It is definitely a possibility for me to upgrade to 9.1 if that will help me.